# Approach for reduced & detailed representation of classes in TypeScript

Tags: angular, class, typescript

## Situation

---

Currently I'm working on a bigger project build with Angular connected to a steadily growing API.

We try to design this API as efficient as possible, meaning that we have different representations of objects e.g. in listing and detail requests.

## Example

---

So as a simple example, the response for a list of users might look like this:

```
{
  users: [
    {
      id: 5,
      firstName: "Foo",
      lastName: "Bar"
    }, 
    {...}
  ]
}
```

While a detailed version of the user contains additional attributes, e.g.:

```
{
  id: 5,
  firstName: "Foo",
  lastName: "Bar",
  photoURL: "https://foo.bar/image.png",
  email: "foo@bar.com"
}
```

Now I'm searching for the cleanest while still maintainable solution for creating a user class, possibilities coming to my mind would be to...

## Possible Solutions

---

#### Create a separate `ListingUser` that's than inherited by a `DetailUser` that's declaring

*Advantage*: Allows clean typing

*Backdrop*: Adding more representations would be pain or not possible if not fitting in the inheritance chain

---

#### Create a single `User` class that contains optional properties

*Advantage*: Single class to maintain

*Backdrop*: You can never be sure which representation you currently have => needs potentially a lot of checks.

---

But maybe I just miss the obvious solution here, would be glad about any input leading me into the right(est) direction to go.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you need a class?

```
interface UserSummary {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

interface User extends UserSummary {
  photoURL: string;
  email: string;
}
```

Any method that returns one or more of these should be explicit about what it returns, so there would be no confusion about which type you have.

```
function getUserSummaries(): UserSummary[] {
    //...
}

function getUsers(): User[] {
    //...
}
```

Placing them in a hierarchy of interfaces (or classes) makes sense as long as they all change for the same reason (you can test this by considering whether adding `middleName` to `UserSummary` should also result in it appearing on `User`). If they are likely to change for different reasons, it would be better to isolate them from each other.

Remember, TypeScript is structural, not nominal, so your types can be "compatible" without explicitly being related.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Actually chose classes for the example as these are for sure more complex in our actual application, so interfaces wouldn't be sufficient for our needs. But regarding the example I've sketched above interfaces would for sure be sufficient as well, agree! 

It's more of a design decision keeping everything clear and understandable while preserving maintainability! So your suggestion would be to split those classes which I (the more I think about it) would also consider over having a huge, but partly filled object. Just both ways don't feel a 100% right to me!